# Split text into lines based on the viewport width in javascript and react

Tags: javascript, reactjs, arrays, string, responsive-design

I have a particular use case in which I want a Text string to split up into single lines. For example, let's say I have this string:

```
const text='Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit Eos blanditiis quia minima dignissimos nostrum accusantium iure quam recusandae modi reiciendis'
```

what I want is this:

```
<div className="line">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing</div>
<div className="line">elit Eos blanditiis quia minima dignissimos nostrum</div>
<div className="line">accusantium iure quam recusandae modi reiciendis</div>
```

Now here lies the problem, I want only single lines and want no wrapping text on the next line. On normal viewports, it would appear as it is but when we go to smaller screens the text would wrap. so here is what I want:

1. Text should be in a single line on every screen size.
2. Numer of words in a single line depends upon the screen size, if the word cannot fit it should be pushed to the next line.
3. There is no required number of lines. It depends upon the number of words that how many lines they can form.
4. I want to implement it in React.

Comment: Confused about your question. It sounds like if the viewport is big enough do not wrap otherwise do wrap the text. the CSS property `word-wrap: break-word;` sounds like what you are looking for, but then you say you don't want word wrapping so I am not quite sure what you are trying to accomplish.

Comment: I agree with @AlexLowe. Here is a link to the MDN docs about CSS properties that can solve your problem: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_text/Wrapping_breaking_text

Comment: Hey Alex thanks for the reply. Well, the main problem is to divide the text into separate divs (with the class of line). What `word-wrap` will do is make the text go to the next line but the parent div will remain the same and the text will stay as a paragraph. I want the text to be divided into separate lines. For example, on a mobile screen, there should only be the first four words from the text because it can only fit those four. The next line should contain the next four words and so on. I hope you understand my explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a React component that dynamically calculates the number of words that can fit within a line and then splits the text accordingly. You can use the useEffect hook to handle window resize events and update the component accordingly.

```js
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";

const LineSplitter = ({ text }) => {
    const [wordsPerLine, setWordsPerLine] = useState(0);
    const dummyElement = document.createElement("div");
    dummyElement.style.display = "inline-block";

    useEffect(() => {
        const calculateWordsPerLine = () => {
            const containerWidth = window.innerWidth;
            dummyElement.textContent = text;

            let words = text.split(" ");
            let lineCount = words.reduce((count, word, index) => {
                const testLine = words
                    .slice(index, index + count + 1)
                    .join(" ");
                dummyElement.textContent = testLine;
                return dummyElement.scrollWidth <= containerWidth
                    ? count
                    : count - 1;
            }, words.length);

            setWordsPerLine(lineCount);
        };

        calculateWordsPerLine();
        window.addEventListener("resize", calculateWordsPerLine);
        return () =>
            window.removeEventListener("resize", calculateWordsPerLine);
    }, [text, dummyElement]);

    const lines = text
        .split(" ")
        .reduce((result, word, index) => {
            const lineIndex = Math.floor(index / wordsPerLine);
            if (!result[lineIndex]) result.push("");
            result[lineIndex] += `${word} `;
            return result;
        }, [])
        .map((line, index) => (
            <div key={index} className="line">
                {line.trim()}
            </div>
        ));

    return <>{lines}</>;
};

const App = () => {
    const text =
        "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet consectetur adipisicing elit Eos blanditiis quia minima dignissimos nostrum accusantium iure quam recusandae modi reiciendis";

    return (
        <div>
            <LineSplitter text={text} />
        </div>
    );
};

export default App;
```

In this example, the LineSplitter component calculates the number of words that can fit within a line based on the container's width. It then uses this information to split the text into separate lines, which are displayed using div elements with the class "line."

[Here](https://playcode.io/1543262) is a running example of the solution over on [playcode.io](https://playcode.io)

Comment: This is overkill for a simple problem that needs no-code to solve. Use CSS instead. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_text/Wrapping_breaking_text

Comment: Hey Ali, thanks for taking the time to comment. I have just checked your implementation but the resulting markup of the component only contains one div with class line. I want the text to be in separate divs each with a class of 'line'. And the number of words in each div depends upon how many can fit in the div. I hope you understand my explanation. Again thanks for the reply!